# how to parallel union dataframes to one dataframe with spark 2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want union data into one dataframe within the foreach loop of another dataframe,but it seems some data lost.

Is there some solutions to solve my situation?  code sample below:

/** set master("local[*]") will lost data,
    set master("local[1]") not lost data.**/

```
object testParallelizeDF extends App {
import scala.util.Random
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

//val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").getOrCreate()//not lost data
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()//lost data

import spark.implicits._

val values0 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var df0 = values0.toDF
df0.repartition(5)

val values = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var df = values.toDF

df0.foreachPartition(p => {
    p.foreach(r => {
        val ran = Random.nextInt()
        println(p.hashCode() + "==>" + r.toString() + "==>" + ran)
        df = df.union(List(ran).toDF)
    })
})

df.collect().foreach(println)}
```

Comment: you cannot use DataFrame API code (i.e. `union`) within `foreachPartition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

union `DataFrames` is parallel per default, you should not try to put that inside executor-side code (it will not work). Also, try to avoid using code with side-effects, use `mapPartitions`/`map` instead of `foreachPartition`/`foreach`:

```
val randomDF = df0.mapPartitions(p => {
    val randomInts = p.map(r => {
        val ran = Random.nextInt()
        println(p.hashCode() + "==>" + r.toString() + "==>" + ran)
       ran
    })

   randomInts
}).toDF()

df.union(randomDF).collect().foreach(println)}
```

you could also generate your random-numbers like:

```
val randomDF = List.fill(df0.count.toInt)(Random.nextInt()).toDF()
```